# Cursor Offset Issue in NVD3 with Viewbox

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, data-visualization, nvd3.js

I have an NVD3 stacked area chart that I have put inside of a viewbox for proper sizing on a website. The chart has one remaining issue which is that the mouseover menu becomes increasingly offset from the cursor as you go from left to right across the chart (see picture).

I have applied a margin on the nvtooltip class in CSS to successfully reposition the tooltip itself, but the actual "SparkLine" (I believe this is what it is called) is still offset from the cursor. I believe this is due to the separate coordinate system on the viewbox, but I have yet to find a solution to address it.

[image: NVD3 Stacked Area Chart]